# Error shown when creating new Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

When I am trying to create new project on Maven in eclipse IDE ,It shows the following errors:

"Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for **org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 ()**"

Anyone please tell what I have to do?

can anyone tell me the steps to create Spring project with Maven enabled?

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>SpringMaven</name>
</project>
```

Comment: show your pom file..There are issues with plugin dependencies

Comment: Are you behind proxy? If so, change network settings in eclipse. If not manually download it and keep it in repo.

Comment: I placed my settings.xml in the .m2 folder and restarted eclipse which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Navigate to user home directory. (For example: "C:\Users\YourUserName\.m2")
3. Delete the "repository" folder.
4. Re-open Eclipse.
5. Click on the Maven project that has an issue and go to "Project" --> "Clean".
6. Right-click on the project and go to "Maven" --> "Update Project...".
7. Close Eclipse.
8. Open Eclipse.
9. Click on the project folder in the "Project Explorer" window (usually on the left).
10. Hit the <kbd>F5</kbd> key a few times to Refresh your project.
11. Done!

These steps worked for me.  If this works for you make sure to upvote, otherwise drop a comment.

Comment: doesn't solve the issue for me :( I am using STS though.

Comment: Solved it for me! (actually by the time I got to step 7 it already worked) Thank you :)

Comment: Year 2022, humans still have to follow 10 steps to make Java projects work...

Comment: did not work now when I click "failed to read artifact" it's blank

Answer (score 2):

Delete maven resource plugin jars (delete the whole folder) from this location - {user.home}.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin and then try to rebuild again.

Comment: I did..but it shows new error..  "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.2"

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Below is my detailed error message:

> **Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution
>   default-resources Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not
>   be resolved**: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6,
>   classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to **central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out**

From the first look, it seems the connection to the central repository failed. But actually it turns out something is f**ked up in my `local repository`.

Rather than spend time to figuring out what's wrong with my `10G` local repository, I use an empty folder as the new local repository.

**And error is gone.**

This is not a solution. This is just a workaround.

I think maven is not robust enough when local repository gets big. And the misleading error message has wasted me a lot of time to check network or proxy issue. Hope it can save other souls some time.

BTW: [Apache Maven Cookbook 2015](http://www.allitebooks.com/apache-maven-cookbook/) is a very good book for Maven starters.

### ADD 1

The chosen answer did essentially similar things to mine.

Answer (score 0):

1. close eclipse, delete the .m2 folder
2. go to "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" and download the certificate and install certificate by using "keytool" for more detail google it.
3. open eclipse and update existing maven project.
4. Now try creating maven project, it should be fine now.