# Error when importing project with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm starting to learn AngularJS and spring at work. I'm following  [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/).

There it has a sample code that you can [download from git](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js.git)

I'm following this steps:

1. Clone the project.
2. `Eclipse -> Import -> maven project -> project called "basic"`( which I download from the git source).

The problem is that maven detects the following errors:

1. > Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
   >   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.   pom.xml /basic  line 1  Maven Configuration Problem
2. > Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
   >   CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.1, com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.2, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2, org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1, com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0, junit:junit:jar:3.8.2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. pom.xml /basic  line 14 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

I really don't understand the error, and I don't know where to look up for a fix.

Comment: As a developer you need to be able to identify unique sentences in error messages, that when searched in Google, will take you to another SO or similar message board for the answer.  In this case "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced" is a highly unique string that would be a good candidate to Google on.

Comment: Most probably the issue is with the Maven import. Open command prompt and navigate to the root directory of the project where pom.xml exits and then run `mvn package` this should download all the required dependencies...

Comment: Just give a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442864/3381825