# Application startup failed - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot from a tutorial I have found in youtube. In the video that I follow, there seems nothing wrong with running his application. I followed everything that he does in the video but there seems a problem to my POM.xml or Application.java file.

Here is my POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>first-springboot-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> And here is my Application.java file

```
    package com.in28minutes.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I searched similar problems in here but their state was different from mine. I am still trying to test if my application could run but it seems having problem and it gives me this error

```
2017-10-22 22:48:13.622 ERROR 9280 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

I don't know what file is causing this error.

Comment: you don't have anything else in your console ?

Comment: No. that's all i have in my console. I am using STS as my IDE.

Comment: I run my project by Run as->Spring boot app

Comment: Which version of STS did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We dont know what exactly the video is describing and which steps you did or dont did. And it looks you are working on a quite new project. So I would recommend you to start a new `spring-starter` project using your IDE `STS` instead of finding any error in your code or video. So you will save time and you will have a running application.

Build on your `pom.xml` you will need `spring-boot` and `spring-web`. I will also say that you use a newer stable version.

So let`s start to create a project:

Go to `File -> New -> Spring Starter Project`

After that you will see a box like that:

[image]

Just add your project name, your group and artifact (could also be the default) and if you want to package the app as `jar`(recommended) or `war`. After that hit next.

In the second box you are able to add your dependencies to your project. In your case you will add `Web`.

[image]

Hit the finish button and your project gets build. You should now be able to start this application directly. Now feel free to follow new steps in the video or try something else. For instance create a `Controller` class.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions sir, but I got an error on the POM.xml on the line

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

Comment: which error do you get? and maybe look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442864/3493036).